# Jquery slick Image are not rendering properly

Tags: jquery, slick.js

Jquery slick is not working properly. One slide image showing in another slide.

I have used jquery slick. I gave overflow hidden for images because they have more width than slide width. but it is not working.

Here is my code:

```
resetSlick(slickElement, MAX_WIDTH = 2400, settings?) {
        if (window.innerWidth < MAX_WIDTH) {
            if (!slickElement.hasClass('slick-initialized')) {
                return slickElement.slick(settings || {
                    dots: true,
                    arrows: false,
                    slidesToShow: 1,
                    slidesToScroll: 1,
                    infinite: true,
                });
            }
        } else {
            if (slickElement.hasClass('slick-initialized')) {
                return slickElement.slick('unslick');
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You probably want to show us your code :) [Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) will be even better.

Comment: I have added code.

Comment: Thanks for the code but I can't see a problem here. Can you reproduce the issue in a snippet? Or http://codepen.io or https://jsbin.com/?html,js,output?